# how to add class to the previous item of the center item in owl carousel 2?

Tags: html, css, jquery-plugins, owl-carousel

I want to add a class to the previous item of the center item. i almost found the answer in the link below :
[How do I add classes to items in Owl Carousel 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900207/how-do-i-add-classes-to-items-in-owl-carousel-2)

That looks great. but the problem is this effect will work on translate which means when click the next button or previous button. how can i get this effect as soon as the page is load?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the item order each time the page is loaded is randomized, you can hard code the class into the previous item of the center item.

Comment: i tried but couldn't . can you help me please. it will be very helpful.