# How to enlarge the image that is in the center (owl-carousel)

Tags: jquery, css, owl-carousel-2

I'd like to do something easy I think with **owl-carousel2,** but unfortunately I can't do it. It is a question of enlarging the image which is in the center each time. I can't find the parameter to add or I tried playing with owl-carousel classes (**owl-item active center**). Even with that, I can't get what I want. 
Initially all the images have the same size, I want to be able to redefine this size when it passes in the middle .

Here's my js:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  items : 5,
  center: true,
  loop:true,
  nav:true,
  slideBy: 1,
  nav: true,
  rewind: false,
  navSpeed: 200,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 7000
})
```

Here is an example : [image]

**And here is my complete code (html, css..)**
: https://jsfiddle.net/MathF/m1knrhd0/14/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a duplicate of this question: [How do I add classes to items in Owl Carousel 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900207/how-do-i-add-classes-to-items-in-owl-carousel-2)

Once you've got the classes in there you can use CSS to size the images.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't seen that question. Sorry about duplicate