# styling left and right child by css

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

Below is a example of how I want my final result will be, however in real life, `<div class="item"></div>` is generated unknown number, so `:nth-child(3)` and `:nth-child(5)` this hard-coded style is not possible. `active center` classes will always be in center child. So, is there any css way can style the child between `<div class="item active center"></div>`

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  background-color:#333;
}
.container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.item{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin:10px;
  opacity:0.2;
}

.item.active.center{
  opacity:1;
}

.item.active:nth-child(3){
   opacity:1;
}

.item.active:nth-child(5){
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item active"> </div>
  <div class="item active"> </div>
  <div class="item active center"> </div>
  <div class="item active"> </div>
  <div class="item active"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
</div>
```

**Like this example**
http://jsfiddle.net/4a5uhm6x/
instead of middle 1 `opacity:1` , need middle of 3 child `opacity:1`

Comment: @sodimel i tried the link as you said is duplicate `:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)` is not the result that i want, it will select all the child that not first and not last, all i need is only the two child between `active center` to be styled

Comment: @sodimel please remove duplicate , it is totally different things

Comment: there is no css that can do this for random numbers of elements - css does not interact with the dom in that way, you would need a js solution (or server side solution to add appropriate classes)

Comment: Can you give an example of the "real life" code?

Comment: @Im Happy: You want the same thing that the guy that asker the other question wanted, but there is currently no solution (for your problem or for his problem). That's why I flagged your question.

Comment: You cannot target the previous sibling by any means using CSS only. I would suggest to target the "3rd" instead and add "+" selector to target the 4th and 5th.

https://codepen.io/yorsaquing/pen/vYBLPEZ

Comment: @S.Visser @Pete @sodimel this is an "real life` example http://jsfiddle.net/4a5uhm6x/ , as you see this carousel only show the middle one is `opacity:1`, however i want it show middle of 3 is `opacity:1`

Comment: @Pete i added example

Comment: I think there is no way to do this without JavaScript.

Comment: In the Owl Carousel you can add custom classes to items. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28900207/how-do-i-add-classes-to-items-in-owl-carousel-2

Comment: @S.Visser yes, your link are able to fix my problem ! Thank you !

Comment: @S.Visser can you add the answer below ? so i can mark as correct , thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment section [you cannot target the previous sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) of an element by just using CSS. I would suggest for you to target the "3rd" element and use the "+" selector to target the "4" and "5" something like this

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  background-color:#333;
}

.container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.item{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin:10px;
  opacity:0.2;
}

.item.active.center{
  opacity:1;
}

.item.active.center + .item,
.item.active.center + .item + .item {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"> </div>
  <div class="item active"> </div>
  <div class="item active center"> </div>
  <div class="item active"> </div>
  <div class="item active"> </div>
  <div class="item active"> </div>
  <div class="item"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is not that i want, this will make the `center` child next two child style only , not between the `center` child

Comment: I see then I think you need to use script for this one

Comment: You can check this its about checking the index and target the next and prev of the current item. I havent clean the code but hope you can get the idea. 
http://jsfiddle.net/y2fm64nb/

Answer (score -1):

item width can be set something like this

```
/* one item */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(1) {
/* -or- li:only-child { */
    width: 100%;
}

/* two items */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(2),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(2) ~ li {
    width: 50%;
}

/* three items */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ li {
    width: 33.3333%;
}

/* four items */
li:first-child:nth-last-child(4),
li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
    width: 25%;
}
```

**or use JS to calculate the number of Items and dynamically set the width**

Answer (score -2):

```
.item{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background-color:#fff;
  margin:10px;
  opacity:0.2;
}
```

Try to set the width in % so, that it covers the whole width.
If there are 7 Item have to use width : 14%

Comment: as i said it is *generated unknown number*